# react-native-permissions: RNPermissions is null in react native and expo

Tags: android, react-native, expo, yarn-workspaces, react-native-permissions

I've forked a repo and want to get it running, it's a react app that I'm running in Android Studio. I've tried starting the app on an emulator and on the browser and I'm getting the same error:

```
index.ts:6 Uncaught Error: react-native-permissions: NativeModule.RNPermissions is null. To fix this issue try these steps:
  • If you are using CocoaPods on iOS, run `pod install` in the `ios` directory and then clean, rebuild and re-run the app. You may also need to re-open Xcode to get the new pods.
  • If you are getting this error while unit testing you need to mock the native module. You can use this to get started: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-permissions/blob/master/mock.js
```

I'm trying to start the app on Android and I'm not running any tests. I start the app with `yarn start`. This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "start-native": "react-native run-ios",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^0.17.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.3.7",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^1.8.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.0",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^4.0.0",
    "expo": "~46.0.9",
    "expo-modules-autolinking": "^0.10.3",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.16.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "moment-countdown": "0.0.3",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "^0.69.5",
    "react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.0.0-rc.6",
    "react-native-permissions": "3.6.1",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4",
    "react-native-progress": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.5.5",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.3.4",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.17.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.6.0",
    "react-native-svg-uri": "^1.2.3",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I realize there are [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59299992/react-native-permissions-returning-rnpermissions-null-in-react-native-expo-proje) about this however so far I have not been able to figure it out. Here are the things that I've tried so far:

1. I've added the following line to `my-app/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />`

2. Removing and reinstalling `node_modules` & `yarn.lock`...several times!
3. Changing the version of `react-native-permissions` from 3.8.0 to 3.6.1
4. I ran `yarn add pod-install`...I don't believe I should have to do this because I'm completely on Andriod at the moment.
5. I ran `yarn add react-native-cli` and `yarn react-native link react-native-permissions`. I get a message saying that `link` is not a recognised command. After some googling, I'm seeing that autolinking should mean I don't have to run this command manually, however, I'm unsure if this is still the case when I'm using `react-native-qrcode-scanner`.